# How to check with Selenium if a row of a scrolled table is visible on the screen?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, html-table

I have a table that is not build with `td` and `tr` tags but each row is a `div` (probably made with css somehow)

Only the visible rows on the screen and a few more are rendered in the DOM.

For example: if rows 7,8,9 are visible on screen then on the DOM I will see rows: 4,5,6,7,8,9

When I scroll for example to rows 13,14,15 what I will see in the DOM will be rows 11,12,13,14,15,16. Rows 4,5,6,7,8,9 are not there anymore.

My question is how can I check with Selenium if a row is currently visible on the screen?

I couldn't find something in `WebDriver`'s API, maybe there is a more low level way with Selenium's class `JavascriptExecutor`?

Comment: could you show us what the html looks like for the rows that are in the DOM?  My guess is that there will be some styling on the "visible" rows that would make it straightforward to identify them with Selenium.

Comment: Check the style attribute by using element.getAttribute("style"). check what it contains in visibility part. Also element.gtCssValue("display")to get the visibility value.

Answer (score 0):

Locate the row element (for example using a css locator) and then find out whether or not is visible:

```
WebElement webElement = webDriver.findElement(By.cssSelector("..."));
boolean isDisplayed = webElement.isDisplayed();
```

Comment: I think isDisplayed checking for a specific class or attributes in the DOM. As I said I have only the visible rows in the DOM and a few more, and no classes or attributes that can distinguish the visible rows from the not visible rows